# Are there any lollipop lock screen settings?

Tags: settings, lock-screens, 5.0-lollipop

On Lollipop it seems that the default "swipe" lock screen has changed a bit for my N5. For years I have been trained to swipe horizontally to unlock the device. Now with the lollipop update swiping horizontally results in launching either the "Phone" or "Camera" shortcut depending on which direction I swipe.

In order to unlock the device I have to swipe upwards in the center.

Ideally I'd like to remove the phone and camera shortcuts from the lock screen altogether and get it so that no matter which direction I swipe the device unlocks.

However I can't seem to find any settings to change this behavior. Does anyone know if there are settings that will allow you to alter or disable the two lock screen shortcuts? (the ability to change them to different applications might be nice too).

Failing any settings that exist to do this does anyone know of an app that I can install that would give me back the functionality of the old lock screen that allows you to swipe horizontally to unlock the device?

*Note: this device is unrooted and running stock OS.*

Comment: In some variants of Lollipop, you can find this setting `Settings > Lock screen > Lock screen shortcuts` and keep both as `None`. I had this option in Cyanogenmod versions cm12 and cm13. But this wont let you unlock swiping horizontally. Thus you may need to install some custom lock screens from Play store.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very clean, minimalist approach to this issue, but it involves the use of a third-party application named [AcDisplay](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.achep.acdisplay). I've used this app in the past and it replaces the traditional lock screen with a rather beautiful one (IMO), with notification access too.

See screenshots:

- First image is a screenshot of the app on my phone.
- Second image is a screenshot of the unlock animation.

  <sub>(Click an image to enlarge it)</sub>

  [image: IMG: This is a screenshot of the app on my Micromax A58]
  [image: IMG: Here is me unlocking it]

You can swipe in any direction.

Comment: @Firelord Thank you for the edits. I didn't really know all this formatting. And I'll keep it in mind to avoid emojis next time around.

Answer (score 0):

Can I also suggest that you take a look at AcDisplay, just because it is a very good third party app, as @Firelord explains.

You should also take a look at other third party lock screen apps when you can; AcDisplay, as far as I know, only allows you to swipe when you get a notification. The time, battery and date isn't  normally on until you get one I think.

I recommend apps such as ZUI locker and Snaplock; these are two of my favourite third party lock screen apps. Please, let me know how you get on and I wish you luck :)