# How to remove camera shortcut on lock screen?

Tags: camera, nexus-6, google-camera

I want to remove the short cut from my phone's lock screen I find it quite annoying and have not found anything in settings or through my own searches. I'd like to get rid of the short-cut in the lower right corner.

I have a sprint nexus 6 phone on stock running android version 6.0.1

Places I have checked already have been linked below for further reference. 
https://www.reddit.com/r/Nexus/comments/2mrsws/disable_lockscreen_in_50/

[Are there any lollipop lock screen settings?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88172/are-there-any-lollipop-lock-screen-settings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking to just eliminate its presence (but not the function), get Xposed framework and this module: [LINK: Xposed repo](http://repo.xposed.info/module/gd.sec.cleanlockscreen). Not just the camera icon - everything you don't want on the lockscreen can be gone.

[image: Screenshot 1]

Also, many custom ROMs such as CM allow you to change where the shortcut goes.

[image: Screenshot 2]

Here I change it to calculator:

[image: Screenshot 3]

All demos done on my own Nexus 6P.

Both require you to unlock and tinker with the phone; then again, what's the reason *not* to do it when you have a Nexus?

Comment: Good points! Note that what's valid for CM also counts for CyanogenOS which some devices ship with. So that option is available on my "stock" Wileyfox Swift, for example. Plus speaking of Xposed: GravityBox allows to even add a row of additional "quick starters" to the lockscreen – a feature also available as separate module :)

Comment: Thanks for the helpful info! I plan to root my phone soon and do some tweaking especially since I just got the 7.0 update. :-) any advice for cool things to look at for that?

Comment: @KazRodgers Not yet... Xposed isn't available for 7.0 right now. I'll stay on CM13 until CM14 is feature-complete and Xposed is usable.

Comment: I tried it on my moto e6i and it didn't go anything.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Nexus, but on Samsung (and I am giving this answer as they share a similar operating system), you need to go to:
Settings > Lock Screen > App Shortcuts (or Shortcuts)
then disable right shortcut or left shortcut, depending on where your camera shortcut is located.
There could be a similar option on a Nexus.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no option to shut that icon down. It was integrated there with the software of android and no way to be removed. It is just like you would like to remove the settings icon from the scroll menu.

Comment: personally I think that too so I'll accept your answer for now. I think switching a setting in developer tools or even a custom ROM may help. But I haven't pursued that yet.